# How to pass data from one js file to another js file through app.js in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `joinQuiz.js` file where users can join a quiz. I want when the user hits the join button, the quiz title and quiz id data to be passed on the next page i.e `quiz.js` file via `App.js` file. I used react-router to navigate through the files

`joinQuiz.js`

```
<Table striped bordered hover>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Quiz
            </th>
            <th>
                 Join
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {info.map((quiz) => (
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h5>{quiz.title}</h5>
                    <p> Creator : {quiz.creator}  {quiz.email}</p>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <Button type="submit" href="/quiz"> Join </Button> //(HERE I WANT TO PASS QUIZ DATA TO NEXT PAGE I.E QUIZ.JS)
                </th>
            </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
</Table>
```

`App.js` file. here I have used react-router to navigate to the files. I don't know if I can directly pass the data from `joinQuiz.js` to `quiz.js` without doing any changes in `app.js`.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/creategame" exact component={createGame} />
          <Route path="/join" exact component={JoinQuiz} />
          <Route path="/quiz"  exact component={Quiz} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </Router> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

`quiz.js`

Here I want to catch the quiz data when the user hits the join button.

```
const Quiz = ( props) => {
    const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
    const [id, setId] = useState('jAApdF8FrX9GSMnDziCxm');
    const [type, setType] = useState('mcq');
    const[name, setName] = useState('');
    const[email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
    const[score, setScore] = useState(0)
    var result = 0
    var response = []
    const array = []

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.post("http://localhost:3500/app/initialdata", { id: id })
            .then((response) => {
                setQuestions(response.data.message)
            })
    }, [])

    return ( 
        <Container style={{paddingTop:"80px"}}>      
            <h3 style={{paddingTop: "20px", marginLeft:"20px"}}>Quiz " **Here I want to print qui title ***  </h3>
            <p style={{marginLeft:"20px"}}>Type : **Here I want to print Quiz Type *** </p>
            <p style={{marginLeft:"20px"}}>Creator : </p>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: is that the whole joinQuiz.js file???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I think you're asking about how to [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).</s>

Quick answer, in one file you must `export` the variable, and the in the other you must `import` it.

`first.js`

```js
export const myConst = 'A string or whatever'
```

`target.js`

```js
import {myConst} from './first.js'

console.log(myConst)
// 'A string or whatever'
```

See the link for more information.

### EDIT

After trying to decipher your problem, I think you might need to use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and a dispatcher. Context is like state that is available to all components within the context provider.

Another way of doing this would be to have state (or a ref) at the App level and pass this as props (as you correctly said) to both the quiz component and the joinQuiz component. Then inside the joinQuiz.js component you set the state to the data you want, before linking to the quiz route, then the data will be available inside the quiz page.

App.js

```js
function App() {
  const [quizState, setQuizState] = useState(null)
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/creategame" exact component={createGame} />
          <Route path="/join" exact component={() => <JoinQuiz setState={setQuizState}/>} />
          <Route path="/quiz"  exact component={() => <Quiz state={quizState} />} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </Router> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

joinQuiz.js (minimal)

```js
import React from 'react';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const JoinQuiz = ({setState}) => {     // setState passed from App.js
  
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleSubmit = (quizData) => (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setState(quizData)             // this is where you set the state you want to use in the other component
    // then navigate to the next page:
    history.push('/quiz')
  }
    
  return (
      <Table>
        ...
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit(quizData)}> Join </Button>
        ...
      </Table>
  );
};

export default JoinQuiz;
```

Quiz.js

```js
const Quiz = ({state}) => {      // this is the quizState that gets set when you click the button.

  ... // your other logic and state etc.

  return ( 
    <Container style={{paddingTop:"80px"}}>      

      ... // the rest of your component

    </Container>
  )
}
```

Incidentally, you will want to use `<td></td>` inside your table body for the cells, rather than `<th></th>` which is for header cells.

### EDIT 2

Here's a really simple example:

```js
const App = () => {

  const [quizState, setQuizState] = useState(null)

  return (
      <div>
        <Route path={'/choose'} component={() => <JoinQuiz setQuizState={setQuizState}/>}/>
        <Route path={'/quiz'} component={() => <Quiz quizState={quizState}/>}/>
      </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const JoinQuiz = ({setQuizState}) => {
  let history = useHistory();

  const handleButtonClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setQuizState({question: "What's the answer?", answer: '42'})
    history.push('/quiz')
  }

  return (
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Join</button>
  );
};
```

```js
const Quiz = ({quizState}) => {
  return (
      <div>
        {quizState.question}
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
  );
};
```

Then after clicking the button you should see something like this:

[image]

I don't think I can break it down for you any more than this! :)

Comment: I did not get it. can you please explain by making required changes in my code which can solve my issue.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear enough for me to do that.

Comment: in my joinQuiz.js file user will be able to join any quiz by pressing the respective button. user will be then brought to the quiz.js file. I want to render the quiz details (like quiz id , quiz type etc) from joinQuiz.js file where the user is being able to join the quiz.

Comment: I know i can do this with props but am not getting correct way to do so..

Comment: See if my edit helps you.

Comment: how to i use the state elements in quiz.js
const Quiz = ({state}) => {      // this is the quizState that gets set when you click the button.

  ... // your other logic and state etc.

  return ( 
{console.log(state)  //this couldn't the correct way to do it
    <Container style={{paddingTop:"80px"}}>      

      ... // the rest of your component

    </Container>
  )
}
how can i access the data being passed

Comment: it's ready to be accessed already. Do `console.log(state)` and you will see it

Comment: getting null value

Comment: have you clicked the button??? It's null until you set it by clicking the button.

Comment: syntax error my bad.......Thank you so much

Comment: I changed my example to include an object instead of a string for the quizState :) Good luck!

Comment: applause to your efforts. Thanks again sir, could not be more grateful.

Comment: Happy to have helped you young sir